# angular scope reference not working

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat, prototypal-inheritance

In the below the ng-show div is not working. I am referencing it from another div but within the controller. pls any help.

```
<div ng-controller="MainCtrl" >
<div data-ng-repeat="choic in choice"  >
<form >
<input ng-model="mustShow"  class="label_align" type="radio" name="customer" value="no"  >
<div class="mediumSubhead"> Information housed </div>
 <br/>        
<input ng-model="mustShow"  class="label_align" type="radio" name="customer" value="yes" >
<div class="mediumSubhead"> Information housed outside </div>
            </form>
</div> 
<div ng-show="mustShow == 'yes'" > ----this part doesnt work
<input name="first_name"  class="text_box_space" type="text" value=""  style="color: black;"  size="25" width="200px" >
</div>
</div>
Controller.js

var app = angular.module('EquityCompensation', []);

  app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {

  $scope.choice = [{id: 'choic1'}];

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are declaring `ng-model` inside `ng-repeat` which is adding that scope variable inside `ng-repeat` scope, because `ng-repeat` does create a new scope on each iteration. You could refer parent scope by using `$parent` notation to point the parent scope variable.

```
ng-model="$parent.mustShow"
```

**Alternative**

You could use dot rule to use prototypal inheritance like

```
$scope.option = {
   'mustShow': false
}
```

Then use like `ng-model="option.mustShow"`